# How to set up port forwarding for postgresql listening on localhost?

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, postgresql

I have a postgresql instance running on SLES.

I want to set it up to listen on localhost, and enable iptables to perform port forwarding.

### My current configuration

postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost'
port = 5432
```

pg_hba.conf:

```
local   all         all                               md5
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0          md5
```

iptables (rule added via `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5432 -j REDIRECT`):

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 441 packets, 54049 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    6   420 REDIRECT   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:5432
```

Configured like this, I am not able to open a psql connection to the DB.

Without the iptables rule, I get a `Connection refused` error.

With the iptables rule I get a `Connection timed out` error.

Comment: Why do you want to use port forwarding?  Can't you just have postgres listen on the ethernet interface?

Comment: nice question!!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check the filter table. For example, what is the default policy for INPUT? Do you have an explicit rule to allow port 5432 if not allowed by CHAIN policy.

Also, it may not be enough to write the rule as shown in your question. Read this from the `man iptables`:

```
REDIRECT
    This target is only valid in the nat table, in the PREROUTING and OUTPUT
    chains, and user-defined chains which are only called from those chains. 
    It redirects the packet to the machine itself by changing the destination IP
    to the primary address of the incoming interface (locally-generated packets are mapped to  the  127.0.0.1 address).
```

So, it will redirect the request to an IP address not necessarily `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. You may need to add the 127.0.0.1 IP address explicitly in the NAT rule. You can try:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5432 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I added the DNAT rule, but this has not changed the results.

Comment: Can you show us your iptables rules in the NAT and filter tables? You can use the commands: `iptables -L -n` and `iptables -L -n -t nat`.