# How to disallow external access to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: linux, networking, nginx, iptables

I use tcp socket on 127.0.0.1:9000 to connect nginx to php5-cgi. However I want make sure that no extrnal request can be made to this IP, so that no attacker can obfuscate IP and bypass nginx to do nasty stuff with php.

Now I am wondering whether it is actually possible to do such exploit, and if so how can I avoid it using iptables?

Comment: this is basic networking that should have been very easy to find

Comment: No external system can connect to 127.0.0.1 on another system.

Comment: @JimB - the problem with many basic networking questions that are obvious is that it's sometimes hard to find a reference to them. Finding the way to block remote access to localhost is not well documented because it's unnecessary and "everyone" just knows that.

Comment: @Johnny, however the community decided a long time ago to not follow the example of stack overflow. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137158/what-is-a-variable for an example of what we decided we didn't want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is not generally possible to access services, bound only to `localhost`, from external addresses.  SF is [fairly](https://serverfault.com/questions/461494/how-to-route-external-tcp-port-80-into-loopback-127-0-0-1-port-8080?rq=1) [replete](https://serverfault.com/questions/458321/forward-public-port-to-localhost) [with](https://serverfault.com/questions/281880/how-to-set-up-port-forwarding-for-postgresql-listening-on-localhost) questions asking how to reverse that state of affairs, and the calisthenics required to do it are non-trivial, precisely because the whole concept of binding only to `localhost` is designed to give you that security without more ado.

Comment: Apparently the same isn't true for IPv6 where [`::1` can be spoofed](http://googleprojectzero.blogspot.de/2015/01/finding-and-exploiting-ntpd.html) depending on your firewall configuration.

Comment: Surely that will be patched, though. No localhost requests should be honored by the kernel/network layer from a physical link.

Comment: @phyrfox That's why it's a bug.  You should not be able to put the loopback traffic on the physical nic regardless of OS

Answer (score 5):

You could create a firewall rule to block this traffic, but it's much easier to enable reverse-path filtering instead.

```
(root)$ echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/rp_filter
```

Reverse-path filtering uses routing tables to filter out spoofed addresses on incoming packets.

You can enable this by default on all interfaces by adding the following to /etc/systcl.conf:

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=1
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=1
```

More info: http://www.slashroot.in/linux-kernel-rpfilter-settings-reverse-path-filtering

**However...**

As already mentioned by MadHatter, this is completely unnecessary for 127.0.0.1/8. (If you want, you can log these packets using `net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1`).